# Can't see cloudwatch logs for my lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

We have a lambda function which is triggered by API gateway. Lambda is returning response properly when I test endpoint in postman. In cloudwatch, it's creating multiple log streams. When I open any one of them, I could only see 2 line related to something like "Runtime Version ARN ...". It's not printing any actual logs from lambda code. It's like it's only creating streams and also, not one stream per api hit but multiple streams without any lambda logs.

I've checked permissions, it has AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole to create logs.
As per documentations, Lambda should automatically create logs in cloudwatch logs. I couldn't figure out what am I missing.

Comment: How is your code logging log messages? If it isn't sending log messages to STDOUT/STDERR, then they aren't going to show up in the log stream. Also it is expected that it will create multiple log streams. Lambda creates one log stream per container.

Comment: Note that you'll see one CloudWatch Logs log stream per Lambda [execution environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtime-environment.html), not one per Lambda invocation.

Comment: We are using log4j to log, added log4j2.xml config for LambdaAppender. Mulitple streams means it's creating multiple empty streams at the same time. Shouldn't it be creating one stream per one execution like when I hit the api endpoint?

Comment: A single Lambda execution environment can handle multiple, non-overlapping requests. They'll all be logged to the same CW log stream. Multiple overlapping (concurrent) requests result in multiple execution environments hence multiple CW log streams. As for log4j, where are the logs being written to? They need to be to stdout/stderr for the default forwarding to CW Logs.

Comment: You didn't really answer the clarification question. How is log4j configured? Is it sending log statements to STDOUT? Is the logging level configured so that it will even log anything?

Comment: For log4j, we have appender config like this https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/s3-java/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml. We've just find out that it's actually logging but in some older log stream. We have a lot of empty log streams. So log stream per execution environment means do we have multiple lambda environments up simultaneously ? Can't figure out how are they being created even if we are not triggering lambda.